# List bullets not displaying correctly in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-lists

I have an `<ol>` with some `<li>`'s in it, in FF it looks good, but for some reason in IE it looks like this:

[image: List Bullet weirdness in IE]

HTML:

```
 <ol start="1">
   <li>Free gifts click here</li>
   <li>Free gifts click here</li>
   <li>Bonus gifts</li>
 </ol>
```

CSS:

```
ol {
    list-style: none outside none;
}
li {
    list-style: decimal outside none;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: What does it look like in FF/IE when you remove the margins?

Comment: I don't think you're providing enough information here. I can't reproduce this. http://jsfiddle.net/Xv3k9/ - works in IE6-9. http://jsbin.com/ejeno6 - (Quirks Mode) works in IE8. Could you provide a test case or a live link to that page?

Comment: I think u have made some styles for the parent of the list (ol) which results like this.. Add the full htmlcode from which you are getting the error

Comment: This is from an intranet system, I can't really post a link.. I used firebug to extract all the relevant css

Comment: You need to make a test case where the bug happens. Try taking the complete source code of your Intranet page (**DON'T** use Firebug. Use plain "View Source".). Copy the relevant stylesheets inline (as in inside `<style>/*CSS here*/</style>`) into your test document. Keep removing stuff and checking that the bug is still there in IE. When you have the smallest working test case possible, add that code to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hasLayout is involved here somewhere it's the cause of `<ol>`'s not numbering correctly as well as a few other lists oddities, you will need to post more CSS for the list so we can see if there is a workaround for your case, but meanwhile here's code that will reproduce it

```
ol {
    list-style: none outside none;
    background: #444;
    color: #fff;
}
li {
    list-style: decimal outside none;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

the key is to keep hasLayout off the `li` element, in order to do that you have to make it so IE does not have to do any counting!,  in this case the left margin means it's having to count to calculate the width -  so if those items inside the list are links, perhaps you could remove the left margin from the `li` and add padding to the links instead?

definitely need more code for the use case though

---

#### Update:

some problems with ordered ;lists aren't curable, and the recommended solution is to wrap the `ol` in a `div` and apply any widths and colouring to that, and any heights to nested elements (like internal links) so that the list elements themselves can be left to default

See the **lists** section on; [On Having Layout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html#list)

> Some of these problems cannot be
>   cured, so when the markers are desired
>   it's better to avoid layout on lists
>   and list elements. If it's necessary
>   to apply some dimension, this is
>   better applied to other elements: for
>   example a width can be applied to an
>   external wrapper, and a height to the
>   content of each list item.

so bearing this in mind and presuming you list elements do contain links (they do say Click Here ;))

```
div {
  width: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
}

ol {
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

a { 
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration:none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #444; 
  background: #fff;
}
```

with

```
<div>
 <ol start="1">
   <li><a href="#">Free Gifts Click Here</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Free gifts click here</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Bonus gifts</a></li>
 </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for recreating it and the explanation. This isn't one I've come across before.

Comment: @thirtydot, thanks, it's a pain this one.. have added the link to the satzansatz article where the oddities that can occur are further explained, be glad when HL is in history ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try adding the property `float: left;` to every `li`:

```
li {
    list-style: decimal outside none;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

---

**Edit:** Also for future reference you may want to make it, just so if you add future rules for `li` they will not overlap and `ol li` remains the most specific.

```
ol li {
    list-style: decimal outside none;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```