# IE 6/7 CSS Issue: Extra padding/margin on list item in unordered list

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm having an issue with IE 6 and 7 on a site I am building, which you can [see here](http://birthrecordslocator.com/). There is some extra space suddenly  appearing between the sidebar and the unordered list for the menu.

Here's IE6
[image]

Here's IE7
[image]

Here's IE8
[image]

and IE9 works as well
[image]

As you can see, IE8 and IE9 work fine. The menu butts up against the sidebar. I have been fooling with it for awhile but haven't been able to fix it.

The HTML structure is just a div > ul > li a

I've zeroed everything out too with a CSS reset before writing any code. Does anyone have any idea what is causing this?

Thanks a ton for the help

Comment: Possibly related to haslayout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801338/list-bullets-not-displaying-correctly-in-internet-explorer

Comment: Doesn't Firebug Lite tell you where it's coming from? Or IE's own debug tools? I agree with Jason though, it's time we all let IE<9 just die already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `display: inline`, `float: left`, and `width: 100%` to your `li`s.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/joshsmith/KapqT/1/)

Tested in [Browserling](http://browserling.com/).

Comment: worked! I added display:inline to the #sidebar ul li then added display:block to #sidebar ul li a

Answer (score 3):

Hard to tell without the CSS.

But I would say a few things:

1. does it need to be pixel perfect for the IE6/7 crowd?  The site looks fine, even with the indents, so a fix may not be necessary.
2. if you do need to fix it, why not use some [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that target IE6/7 and then set a negative margin.

Comment: It doesn't need to be pixel perfect but I just wanted to up my skills and figure out why it was doing that. Thanks for the help! I appreciate you takin the time!

Answer (score 1):

You need to normalize your styles for better portability, there are slight differences in the defaults between browsers.

http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to add these lines before head tag in html page.

```
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ --> 
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="no-js ie6 ieb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="no-js ie7 ieb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="no-js ie8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9 ]>    <html class="no-js ie9" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html class="no-js" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

2) According to IE browser version specific class is added to your html container by these lines.

3) Then you can add specific css file for ie css issues.

4) In that file you have to mention property according to that browser.

In your case you can do like this:
Added class to that ul: bd_links

```
ie6 ul.bd_links,ie7 ul.bd_links,
{
margin-left:-20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check by putting

```
ul, li {
   list-style-position: inside;
}
```

If you already zerod every padding margin.